# How to implement "falling pins"

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I am trying to show pins falling from the sky to the final destination point. But all I've found so far is how to place all the pins in an overlay and then in the next screen show all the pins at the same time. If I have an array of points (latitudes and longitudes) how do I show the pins falling from the sky one pin at a time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need the `DROP` animation:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    draggable:true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: parliament
  });
```

from here:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#MarkerAnimations

Here is a good example page:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markeranimations/markeranimations.html

Fyi... not sure how this works for Android.

Comment: How sad, apparently we need to make a custom overlay to create the effect and I have no idea how to start.